# How to disable the comment for a specific node programmatically?

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8. I would like to close the comment for the node, once someone commented on that node. But I don't know how to disable the comment for a specific node programmatically.

```
my_module_comment_insert ($entity) //implement the comment insert hook
{
    $node = $entity->getCommentedEntity();//get the attached comment node.
    // How to implement code here to disable comment for the $node? 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In D8, the comments are stored as field containing various comment properties including comment `status`.

You can disable node/entity comments using something like below:

```
use Drupal\comment\Plugin\Field\FieldType\CommentItemInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_insert().
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_comment_insert($comment) {
  // Get comment field name, default comment.
  $field_name = 'comment'; // $comment->getFieldName();

  // Get entity.
  $node = $comment->getCommentedEntity();
  $node->get($field_name)->status = CommentItemInterface::CLOSED;
  $node->save();
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped.